# XSLT not rendering

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm doing this simple XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl ="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <h1>El meu primer document XSLT</h1>
    <xsl:for-each select="pisos/pis">
      <strong>id:</strong>
      <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is my XML file:

```
<Stock_pisos>
 <pisos>
    <pis>
      <id>1</id>
    </pis>
  </pisos>
</Stock_pisos>
```

However, the document just renders the H1 title.

Any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select the root element first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl ="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <h1>El meu primer document XSLT</h1>
      <xsl:for-each select="Stock_pisos/pisos/pis">
      <strong>id:</strong>
      <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In terms of the code posted your suggestion is correct but the terminology "`root node`" is wrong in the context of XSLT/XPath as http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node is selected by `/` and means the document node and not the root element. So I think you want to say "select the `root element`".